# workflow_run not working for more than 4 subsequent runs

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

I am using workflow_run to run my workflow on the completion of other workflows.

but this is not working after  4 subsequent runs.

As you can see in the attached screenshot(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q2tU.png) , I have 7 workflows, Test2 should work after completion of Test 1 and Test 3 after Test2 and Test4 after Test3.......

but it's not working after running workflow Test4.

Is this a known limitation ? Can we work around this limit or make the limit higher ?

```
name: Test5
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Test4"]
    types:
      - completed
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - experimental/*
      - release/*
      - feature/add_github_actions
jobs:
  on-success5:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${​​​​​​​{​​​​​​​ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​
    steps:
      - name: Say Hello World
        run: echo "hello world"
```

Comment: Could you share your repository to fork it and try to reproduce the issue please?

Comment: here we go, https://github.com/ajeetvolvo/github_actions_test

Comment: I checked and tested your implementation, and everything looks ok. Therefore I checked the documentation and found the section regarding this limitation. I added it as official answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, but according to the documentation related to [workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run), there is a section that states:

> **You can't use `workflow_run` to chain together more than three levels of workflows**. For example, if you attempt to trigger five workflows (named `B` to `F`) to run sequentially after an initial workflow `A` has run (that is: `A` → `B` → `C` → `D` → `E` → `F`), workflows `E` and `F` will not be run.

Therefore, you won't be able to achieve what you want using `workflow_run` alone.

*Note: A workaround could be to use a [`dispatch_event`](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) to start a new sequence of 3 workflow runs in the 4th workflow.*